# No connection to MySQL from PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

EDIT:
The first script get no errors, only a white screen.
And so I tested a while and here the result. (And learned the basics...)

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /var/www/tabelle/pizza/test_pdo3.php on line 11

First the PDO version, after that a version without PDO which work.

```
<?php

//Connect
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;pizzadb3', 'auser', 'passw',
array('charset'=>'utf8'));

//Ausführen des Querys mit möglicher Fehlerbehandlung per try, catch
$stmt = $db->query('select * from pizzeria_table');

//Anzahl ermitteln
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();

echo 'Anzahl: '.$row_count.'<br/>';

//Jeder Datensatz aus $stmt wird zur Ausgabe in ein temp-Array $row gespeichert
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['laden_name'].' / '.$row['vorwahl'].'<br/>';
}

?>
```

This version do what to do.

```
<?php

//Connect
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'passw');
mysql_select_db('pizzadb3', $conn);
mysql_set_charset('UTF-8', $conn);

$sql = "select * from pizzeria_table";

//Ausführen des Statements und evtl. Fehlerbehandlung mit 'die'
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

//Anzahl der Datensätze ermitteln
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo 'Anzahl: '.$row_count.'<br/>';

//Jeder Datensatz aus $result wird zur Ausgabe in ein temp-Array $row gespeichert
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['laden_name'].' / '.$row['vorwahl'].'<br/>';
}

?>
```

What could I do?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML code that is generated by the PHP code? Are you sure you should see something? Is there content in the table? Have you tried making a small program that only contains the core functionality, so it's easier testing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: with a small testfile and without PDO all works fine. In the big file you can see a button and an empty table with one cell. I 'm just trying a file with PDO.

Comment: Turn on PDO exceptions, [as documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` then see if you get any errors.

Comment: Have used a the first test script from the link, all white. Tested a wrong password. Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Done the same in the big script, with a right and wrong password, all the same. Maybe my database table is empty, but it isn't. Tested with wrong table name:Error!: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pizzadb3.pizzeria_table_test' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;pizzadb3`

Needs to be: `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pizzadb3;`